# Why is TextWriter.Write(char) not abstract?

Tags: c#, .net

`TextWriter` is an abstract class with one abstract function - `Encoding Encoding { get; }`. Implementations must also implement `void Write(char)`, but this function is not abstract - why? The default implementation does nothing which for me does not make sense.

Comment: The documentation says `A derived class must minimally implement the TextWriter.Write(Char) method to make a useful instance of TextWriter` - maybe they wanted you to be able to make a *not useful* instance? :D

Comment: @Rawling: yes, I guess this is minor details, but I would expect a not useful implementation to explicitly implement `Write(char)` to do nothing. As it is implemented, subclassing `TextWriter` is not really intuitive as you need to read the documentation to know that `Write(char)` is the function you need to implement (and not all the other `Write`-functions).

Comment: A naive implementation would write everything via `Write(char)` :D Also makes a `NullTextWriter` super easy to implement

Comment: @larsm - I'd suggest that if you're deriving from any class and *not* consulting its attendant documentation, you're not doing a good job. There are plenty of requirements one might wish to communicate to those who will derive that are not enforceable purely through code constructs.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I'm not sure if I agree with your argument. `TextWriter` is a well known class - I very well known its intention and what it does. Making `void Write(char)` abstract would make it [self-describing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting). I would rather state the opposite; if you write an abstract class and that it is required to read all the documentation in order to create a subclass, you're not doing a good job.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm not familiar with `MarshalByRefObject`, but how does `Encoding TextWriter.Encoding { get; }` differ from `Write` in this regard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a design error in `TextWriter`. According to Reflector, all other `Write*` methods reduce to  `Write(char)`. The documentation says something similar. `Write(char)` should be abstract.

A developer not noticing this might be mislead to create an implementation that mostly works, but when writing a `char` (which is uncommon) it might do nothing. Surprising behavior.

If you derive from `TextWriter` and you know that callers will only use certain overloads such as `Write(string)` you can save some work by only overriding the necessary methods and ignoring `Write(char)`. That, however, violates the Liskov substitution principle. Back when the BCL was designed they might not have taken a strict stance on the SOLID principles.

The [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs) is not enlightening:

```
    // Writes a character to the text stream. This default method is empty,
    // but descendant classes can override the method to provide the
    // appropriate functionality.
    //
    public virtual void Write(char value) {
    }
```

Comment: "The documentation says something similar." - not quite. [The documentation says "This default method does nothing"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.write?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_TextWriter_Write_System_Char_) - but I do *wish* it did say "this method should be abstract".